# Verifying two proofs about connected sets

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A_n$ be a sequence of connected sets such that $A_n \cap A_{n+1}\neq \emptyset$.  Show that $\cup A_n$ is connected.

Let $A=\cup A_n$.  Suppose $A$ is separable and let $U,V$ be a separation of $A$.  Then, we know that $A_n \subseteq U$ or $A_n \subseteq V$ for each $n$.  But since $A_n \cap A_{n+1}\neq \emptyset$ we know that $A_n \subseteq U$ or $A_n \subseteq V$ for all $n$.  Thus $A$ is not separable since either $U$ or $V$ is empty.

> Let $X$ be an infinite set.  Show that it is connected in the finite complement topology.

Let $U,V$ be a separation of $X$ such that $X\setminus U=V$ and $X\setminus V=U$.  Then, both $U$ and $V$ are finite, and $U\cup V=X$ - a contradiction since $X$ is an infinite set.

Comment: They’re both basically right. You shouldn’t use the word *separable* in this way, though: in a topological context it means *has a countable dense subset*.

Comment: Should I say not connected instead?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: You're using the symbol "$\in$" where you should be using the symbol "$\subset$" in places ...

Comment: Oops; I missed that. @David is quite right.

Comment: For the first one, it could be convenient to use the following characterization: $A$ is connected iff every continuous $f:A\longrightarrow\{0,1\}$ (discrete) is constant. Then take such a continuous map on $\bigcup A_n$. It is continuous whence constant on each $A_n$. By the condition and an induction, all these constants must coincide.

Comment: @David Thanks for pointing that out.  In my head, I was saying that those sets were in the other.  On my final copy I used the correct symbol of $\subseteq$.